# Is it posible to have 2 Web Services on the same machine that use DNX and dotnet CLI respectively

Tags: asp.net-core, publish

I have a machine with installed DNX (beta-8) and running ASP.NET 5-beta8 API Service. And what I need is to publish another one API service, that have been created using ASP.NET Core 1.0.

So I'm worried if I do not break the current old Service if I install .NET Core Tooling on this machine.

Unfortunately, I don't have an option to update old API Service to ASP.NET Core 1.0

Comment: Worst case, separate VMs on the same host machine.

Comment: You'll have to update it anyways, dnx isn't in development and deprecated anyways. dotnet cli is the new way... and the only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you *should* be able to run dnx and dotnet side by side but it's not an officially supported scenario. The only known issue is that you cannot have VS tooling that supports both. However, if you build/publish from console, it should work.

That being said, `dnx` is deprecated and it will not updated in the future.